# Do i need a mutex for a static function?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, mutex

I have a C++ class with a static function:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    static void bar(int &a)
    {
        a++;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
The variable passed as argument is only used within the calling scope. So it is not accessed by another thread.

Do i have to use a `mutex` when i call this function from a seperate thread?

Thanks.

Comment: Depends on how `a` is used elsewhere. Can `a` be any `int`? How do you guard it properly if it can be anything? You probably need to use your lock before calling `bar`.

Comment: The answer is rather complex unless you can provide more info as to how this function is going to be used. It is the variables that are passed into this function that need protecting rather than the function itself.

Comment: @Galik: Your second sentence disproves your first, in that the answer to this question is extremely simple.

Comment: _"it is not accessed by another thread"_ _"when i call this function from a seperate thread"_ Okay a separate thread to what then?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Calling this function requires only thread-local resources, the stack of thread. Therefore the answer is no. If the int variable is accessible by more than the calling thread, you will need a `mutex` for the variable

Answer (score 5):

Whether a function is `static` has no bearing on whether calls to it need to be synchronised.

The determining factor is whether the function is re-entrant, and what you do with the data. In this case, the function *is* re-entrant (as it has no non-local state of its own, or in fact any state at all), and the data is owned/managed by the calling scope, so you will have to decide within the calling scope whether that integer requires protection.

But this is true whether `bar` is a static member, a non-static member, a free function, a macro, a cat, a black hole, or Jon Skeet's tumble dryer.

Comment: Just curious. Why did you change your name and than reverted it back?

Comment: I know. Didn't imply that it was flipped overnight. The question still stands.

Comment: Fair enough. Like I said, just being curious.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to mention that mutex is not the only thread synchronization primitive available, and in some scenarios far from most approriate one.

Provided synchronization is needed (see two other answers on why it might be needed depending on usage) don't jump into mutex world. For something as straitghtforward as a counter (this is what I see in the code) *atomic* variables (or, in absence of those, atomic operations on non-atomic types) often provide a better performance and more straightforward code.

In this particular case, incrementing a variable can be easily done in thread-safe way with following C++11 code:

```
static void bar(std::atomic<int>& a)
{
    a.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
}
```

`memory_order_relaxed` used here is really far-fetched, and not neccessarily applicable (however, often good for counters). Used here mostly for the example.